# IDA SDK Extract Offset From Instruction

Tags: ida, disassemblers, idapro-sdk

`get_screen_ea( )` is ==

```
.text:000000014000B065 mov cs:qword_142167D38, rcx
```

Is there a function in the SDK to extract **qword_142167D38**? Preferably as a hexadecimal value rather than a string.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating on existing answers, if you prefer to use IDAPython:

```
decode_insn(here())
print hex(cmd.Op1.addr)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char szBuffer[MAXSTR];
ua_outop2( get_screen_ea( ), szBuffer, MAXSTR, 1 );

ea_t qword = cmd.Operands[1].addr;
```

Comment: Easier to use use `decode_insn()`.

Answer (score 1):

Again for IDAPython:

```
mov     dword_40C4A4, eax
```

I just use GetOperandValue for stuff like that:

```
Python>"%08x" % GetOperandValue(ScreenEA(),0)
0040c4a4
```